# Count two different columns values from the same table using SQLite Database table in android

Tags: sqlite, android-sqlite

I am trying to select multiple values from the same table. I need to select count values of the column rfid and process_status from the posts table and station_title from stations table.

Here are the two tables:

**Posts table :**

```
Id   ownerId   rfid    stationId      stationType    process_status
1       107        rfid1  raj1222681607   like             pending
2       107        rfid1  raj1222681607   like             pending
3      107        rfid1  raj1125396157    like             pending
4       107        rfid1  raj1222681607   like             
5       107        rfid2  raj1222681607   like             pending
6       107        rfid3  raj1222681607   like
```

**Stations table :**

```
Id   title    ownerId    stationId     stationLike    stationPic
1    Check-in one         107             raj1125396157    1              0
2    nfc station 01      107             raj1222681607     1             0
```

From these two tables I want to fetch data as

```
Total RFIDs : 5
Total Pending : 3
Station Title : nfc station 01
```

The where clause conditions are : ownerId = 107 and the stationId = 'raj1222681607' and the process_status = 'pending'

So far I can achieve the total rfids, station title value; but i am not able to get the total pending value counting the process status.

My query snippet:

```
  SELECT
        COUNT(p.rfid) as TotalTap,
        COUNT(p.process_status) as TotalPending,
        s.title
    FROM posts p
    inner join
    stations s
    on p.stationId = s.stationId
    WHERE
    p.ownerId = 107 AND p.stationId = 'raj1222681607'
    AND p.process_status = 'pending';
```

But this is giving the wrong output as :
         Total RFIDs : 3 (THIS IS WRONG!!)
         Total Pending : 3
         Station Title : nfc station 01

Answer (score 1):

To compute how many rows match a condition, use SUM over a boolean expression:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS TotalTap,
       SUM(process_status = 'pending') AS TotalPending
FROM Posts
WHERE ownerId = 107
  AND stationId = 'raj1222681607';
```

It does not really make sense to try to compute the third value in the same query; just use a separate, much simpler query:

```
SELECT title
FROM Stations
WHERE stationId = 'raj1222681607';
```

Android has a [helper function](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.html#stringForQuery%28android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29) for this:

```java
String title = DatabaseUtils.stringForQuery(db,
                   "SELECT title FROM Stations WHERE stationId = ?",
                   new String[]{ "raj1222681607" });
```

Comment: Hi CL, thanks for the correction. The process status value is string format. so sum will be the good option? i need to fetch all these information from one db function calling. so i need to also get the title value.

Comment: The value of the expression `process_status = 'pending'` is either `0` or `1`.

Comment: my query is :  SELECT
            COUNT(p.rfid) as TotalTap,
            (SELECT COUNT(p.process_status) FROM posts p WHERE p.ownerId = ? AND p.stationId = ? AND p.process_status = ?) as TotalPending,
            s.title
        FROM posts p
        inner join
        stations s
        on p.stationId = s.stationId
        WHERE
        p.ownerId = 107 AND p.stationId = 'raj1222681607' and p.process_status = 'pending'; but i can't get these values from the cursor call.

Comment: That is a different query.